# What is the difference between a simple composite class and uibinder in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder, composite

I want to create a widget in GWT. there is two methods exist .

### 1.GWT UI:BINDER

```
 public class Login extends Composite {

  private static LoginUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(LoginUiBinder.class);

  /*
   * @UiTemplate is not mandatory but allows multiple XML templates
   * to be used for the same widget. 
   * Default file loaded will be <class-name>.ui.xml
    */
   @UiTemplate("Login.ui.xml")
   interface LoginUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, Login> {
   }
   ...
 }
```

and XML file is

```
 <ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
  xmlns:gwt='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui' 
  xmlns:res='urn:with:com.tutorialspoint.client.LoginResources'>
  <ui:with type="com.tutorialspoint.client.LoginResources" field="res">
  </ui:with>
  <gwt:HTMLPanel>

   </gwt:HTMLPanel>
 </ui:UiBinder>
```

### 2 Using Composit

```
 public class HelloWorld implements EntryPoint {

   /**
    * A composite of a TextBox and a CheckBox that optionally enables it.
    */
private static class OptionalTextBox extends Composite  {


  public OptionalTextBox(String caption) {

     VerticalPanel decoratorPanel = new VerticalPanel();

     initWidget(decoratorPanel);
  }

 }
```

so I am confused which method is good to use. is there any difference. I used both methods but havent any idea.

Answer (score 2):

You are showing the same method. In both of your examples a new widget extends Composite. There will be no meaningful difference in the compiled code.

The only difference is that one example uses UiBinder, while the other one does not.

Personally, I prefer to use UiBinder unless I am creating a very simple widget with no styles and no text strings (my apps are internationalized). In my experience, UiBinder templates are easier to maintain and trouble-shoot.